# What would happen if you have one Clash of Clans account on 2 devices and I delete the app on one of them?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I was wondering what would happen if I had two devices both using the same Clash of Clans account and I delete the app on one of my devices. I would just like to know if it will delete all my Clash of Clans data or just delete it from that device.

Answer (score 2):

If you will delete the game itself on one of your devices, it will not delete all your COC data, the game will just be removed in your device. If you try downloading COC again, all your previous data will still be there.

[ I already tried this before. My uncle played his account on my iPad (Even if he could still play it on his iPhone). I wanted to make my own account, so I tried to delete the game thinking my uncle's COC data in my iPad will go away. (When I deleted his COC in my iPad, he could still play it on his iPhone.) So I downloaded it again, but I saw that his account is still there in my iPad. No matter what I do, it couldn't be removed from my iPad. :( ]

Comment: This is probably because you were still logged into your Uncle's Game center account.